# Real Analysis: Connected set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B(0,r)$, a open ball with center 0 and radius $r>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Prove that, if $n\geq 2$, then $B(0,r)-\{0\}$ is a connected set.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: show path concertedness, which implies connectedness

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x,y\in B(0,r)\setminus \{0\}$ satisfying $0\notin[x,y]$, one has
$$ |x|\le r, |y|\le r. $$
For $t\in[0,1]$,
$$ |tx+(1-t)y|\le t|x|+(1-t)|y|\le tr+(1-t)r=r $$
and hence the line $[x,y]$ is in $B(0,r)\setminus \{0\}$. So $x$ and $y$ are connected. If $0\in[x,y]$, choose $z\in B(0,r)\setminus \{0\}$ such that $z$ is not in the line $[x,y]$. Then the lines $[x,z]$ and $[y,z]$ are in $B(0,r)\setminus \{0\}$ and hence $x,y$  connected. Therefore $B(0,r)\setminus \{0\}$ is connected.

Comment: Even if $x \neq -y$, $0$ might be in the line segment $[ x, y ]$. You should consider the cases $0$ is or is not in $[ x, y ]$.

Comment: @v_lentin, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short answer if you know that fact that $\{x: \|x|| >R\}$ is connected for any $R>0$: define $g:\{x: \|x|| >\frac 1 r\}\to \{x: \|x|| <r\}\setminus \{0\}$ by $g(x)=\frac x {\|x\|^{2}}$. Then $B(0,r)\setminus \{0\}$ is simply the image under the continuous function $g$ of the connected set $\{x: \|x|| >\frac 1 r\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in B(0,r) -\{0\}$, such that $x \not= y$

We have $\|x\| \not= 0 \neq \|y\|$

Suppose $x \not= -y$ and $\|x\| = \|y\|$

let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$

$f(t) = (1-t)x + ty$

Then, $f(t) = 0 \iff (1-t)x = -ty \iff \frac{(1-t)}{-t} x = y $

($t$ can not be $0$ well $x\not= 0$)

So $f(t) = 0 \implies \frac{(1-t)}{t}\|x\| = \|y\| \implies \frac{(1-t)}{t} = 1 \implies t = \frac{1}{2}$

But, $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2} = 0 \iff x = -y$

Then $f(t) \not= 0$ for all $ t \in [0,1]$

$f(0) = x$, $f(1) = y$

And $\|f(t)\| = \|(1-t)x+ty\| \leq (1-t) \|x\| + t \|y\|<(1-t)r + rt = r$

Then $f$ connect $x$ with $y$ in $B(0,r) -\{0\}$

Now suppose $x = -y$

if $x = (\|x\|,0,0,...,0)$, then I can connect as in the previous case $x$ with $z = (0,\|x\|,0,...,0)$ and then connect $z$ with $y = -x = (-\|x\|,0...,0)$

The same if $x = (-\|x\|,0,...,0)$

Now, if $x \not= (\|x\|,0,...,0)$ and $x \not= (-\|x\|,0,...,0)$

I can connect as in the previous case $x$ with $(\|x\|,0,...,0)$ and then connect as in the previous case $(\|x\|,0,...,0)$ with $y = -x$

This way I can connect all points $x,y$ such that $\|x\| = \|y\|$

Now if $\|x\| < \|y\|$

Let $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$

$g(t) = (1-t)x + tx\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}$

$g(0) = x$ and $g(1) = x \frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}$

$\|g(t)\| = \|(1-t)x + t \frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}\| \leq (1-t)\|x\| + t\|x\| \frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}= (1-t)\|x\| + t\|y\| < (1-t)r + tr = r$

$g(t) = 0 \iff (1-t)x = -tx\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|} \implies (1-t)\|x\| = t\|y\| \implies \frac{(1-t)}{t}\|x\| = \|y\| \implies t = \frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|+\|y\|}$

But $g(\frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|+\|y\|}) = (1-\frac{\|x\|}{\|x\| + \|y\|})x + \frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|+\|y\|}x\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|} = \frac{\|y\|x}{\|x\|+\|y\|} +\frac{\|y\|x}{\|y\|+\|x\|} \not= 0$

Then $g(t) \not= 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$

Then $g(t) \in B(0,r) - \{0\}$ for all $t\in [0,1]$

And $g$ connect $x$ with $z=x\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}$

And since $\|z\| = \|x\|\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|} =  \|y\|$ then I can connect $z$ with $y$ like at the beginning

And we are done, I hope

Answer (score 0):

Following on the comment left by @Hagen von Eitzen, it is perhaps most "natural" to show that the sets are not just connected, but path-connected, which implies the former. To do that, we need to show that for any two points $P$ and $Q$ in the pierced $n$-ball, that there is a continuous path between them.

Due to the (hyper)spherical symmetry, the most "natural" way to do this may be to represent $P$ and $Q$ in hyperspherical coordinates:

$$P = (p_\rho, p_{\theta_1}, p_{\theta_2}, \cdots, p_{\theta_{n-2}}, p_{\phi})$$

and

$$Q = (q_\rho, q_{\theta_1}, q_{\theta_2}, \cdots, q_{\theta_{n-2}}, q_{\phi})$$

where, if we label the Cartesian axes as $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, $p_\rho$ and $q_\rho$ are, of course, the distances from the origin, which thus must be in the *doubly-open* ranges $(0, r)$ - note how easy that makes it to exclude the origin point!, and the inclinational angles $p_{\theta_1}$, $p_{\theta_2}$, etc. are measured respectively from the axes $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2$, $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3$, etc. and $\phi$ from the last axis. The ranges are that $\theta_j$ is in $[0, \pi)$ and $\phi$ is in $[0, 2\pi)$. With that, a path between the two points can be constructed as follows:

1. Move radially from $P$ to $(q_\rho, p_{\theta_1}, p_{\theta_2}, \cdots, p_{\theta_{n-2}}, p_{\phi})$, i.e. radially, in a straight line, change distance from the origin from $p_\rho$ to $q_\rho$
2. (If $n > 2$) Move inclinationally from $(q_\rho, p_{\theta_1}, p_{\theta_2}, \cdots, p_{\theta_{n-2}}, p_{\phi})$ to $(q_\rho, q_{\theta_1}, p_{\theta_2}, \cdots, p_{\theta_{n-2}}, p_{\phi})$, i.e. now swivel your $\theta_1$ coordinate along a suitable arc, starting from the previous point, so it aligns with that of $Q$. Repeat this for the remaining $\theta_j$, starting from the prior point.
3. Finally, move azimuthally from $(q_\rho, q_{\theta_1}, q_{\theta_2}, \cdots, q_{\theta_{n-2}}, p_{\phi})$, i.e. the last point attained in step 2 (if we did it, i.e. $n > 2$, otherwise we're just moving $\phi$ starting from $P$) to $Q$, i.e. vary the $\phi$ coordinate to form one last arc.

It should be easy to see that the path described is continuous - all its segments are either straight lines or circular arcs, and the endpoint of one is the initial point of the following one. Hence, there is a continuous path between any $P$ and $Q$. Moreover, since the radial coordinate is always in $(0, r)$ - namely, at most it changes over the interval $(p_\rho, q_\rho)$ - we see that all points involved are within the pierced ball. Thus we have a continuous path, within the pierced ball, between any two points also within it. Thus the pierced ball is path-connected, hence connected.